# VBA Assign score to cell text and pass into formula

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel I have a three columns containing either the letters A, B or C. In this scenario the letters have a score, A=1, B=2 and C=3. In column 4 I need a VBA code to simply sum up the score based on the cell text and display in the fourth column.

A+B+C = 6, A+A+B = 4 and so on.

In practice I will have more text than A B and C, this is just for simplicity.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to add the score to each letter to pass to the formula, my work around has been to use an existing reference table in the spread sheet. This isn't ideal as I have this requirement in multiple workbooks.

Comment: You say you have more text that `A, B and C`. Is it always a single character between A and Z e.g. A = 1, Z = 26?

Comment: No, the text will be between 1-3 characters in length. There is a finite range of possible variations which need scores assigned.

Comment: The score is not linked to the characters position in the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary (you'll need to reference the Microsoft.ScriptingRuntime in the VBA editor, via Tools...References) and code like this:

```
Private Sub getScore()

  Dim d As dictionary
  Set d = New dictionary

  d("a") = 1
  d("b") = 2
  d("c") = 3

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim score As Integer
  Dim cellData As String
  cellData = Cells(1, 1).Value


  ' Loop through the characters in the cell
  For i = 1 To Len(cellData)

    'Loop through the dictionary to see if a match exists
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 0 To d.Count - 1

       If Mid(cellData, i, 1) = d.Keys(x) Then
          score = score + d.Items(x)
       End If
    Next x

  Next i

  MsgBox ("Score is: " & score)


End Sub
```

Comment: having a play with this to get the desired outputs but the dictionary has solved my problem. Thanks, nice code

Comment: @Freddie G You're welcome. How about a +1 and marking it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

With data in rows **1** through **17**, run this short macro:

```
Sub Freddie()
    With Range("D1:D17")
        .Formula = "=countif(A1:C1,""A"")*1+countif(A1:C1,""B"")*2+countif(A1:C1,""C"")*3"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

This can easily be modified to handle any number of character values.